# Excel VBA all of a sudden running slowly

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have an excel workbook:

- with several sheets

  - Some (5) of which have rows that are contextually hidden using a Macro (for example if the value in cell B2 = "Hide", then the Macro will hide the entire row)

Recently however the Macro to hide rows is running slowly, for example a sheet with less than 200 rows takes up 15 seconds to run.

Note that I have a separate sub for each sheet, I then "Call" these subs at the click of a  user button

I have experimented with running a hide row sub on just one of the sheets (i.e. not using the Call Macro)

The code is simple and does not use "Select" or "Activate".
I have tried:

- Removing sheet protection (which ive read can slow the macro)
- Setting the RowHeight to zero instead of hiding rows ( I thought that might speed it up, but didnt)

See Below - Code for just ine Sub from one sheet

---

```
Sub HideRowsEmissionsCalc_1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' MsgBox ("Working on Scope 1 & 2")
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Scope I & II Emiss")

'    With ws1
'        .Unprotect Password:="MOS"
'    End With
'
For Each cell In ws1.Range("B3:B178")
If cell.Value = "Hide" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cell

'    With ws1
'        .Protect Password:="MOS"
'    End With
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the workbook shared or on a network drive eg one drive?

Comment: Do you have any "event" codes that might get triggered by hiding rows?  Even if not, flipping the `Application.EnableEvents` flag the same way you do for the `Application.ScreenUpdating` flag won't hurt.  I've had programs in the past that unexpectedly trigger events that extend the runtime considerably.

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a procedure for each sheet.  Have your procedure in a normal module and tell it which sheet to look at and optionally which columns.

**Edit:** First thought was to use Autofilter, but can also use Find to find the "Hide" rows.

Using Find:

```
Sub Test()
    'Hide rows on Sheet1 using default location of last row check and "Hide" column.
    HideDataRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), "MOS"
    
    'Hide rows on Sheet2 where last row is calculated using column B, and "Hide" appears in column G.  Sheet not password protected.
    HideDataRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), LastRowCol:=2, CheckColumn:=7
    
    HideDataRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"), "SOM", 1, 2
End Sub

Public Sub HideDataRows(WrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Pwd As String = "", Optional LastRowCol As Long = 3, Optional CheckColumn As Long = 2)

    With WrkSht
        If Pwd <> "" Then
            .Unprotect Pwd
        End If
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Range is one row above the data you want to filter.
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CheckColumn), .Cells(LastRow, CheckColumn))
    End With
    
    With DataRange
        Dim rw As Range
        Set rw = .Find(What:="Hide", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        
        If Not rw Is Nothing Then
            Do
                rw.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Set rw = .FindNext(rw)
            Loop While Not rw Is Nothing
        End If
    
    End With

    If Pwd <> "" Then
        WrkSht.Protect Pwd
    End If

End Sub
```

Using Autofilter:

```
Sub Test()
    'Hide rows on Sheet1 using default location of last row check and "Hide" column.
    HideDataRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), "MOS"
    
    'Hide rows on Sheet2 where last row is calculated using column B, and "Hide" appears in column G.  Sheet not password protected.
    HideDataRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), LastRowCol:=2, CheckColumn:=7
    
    HideDataRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"), "SOM", 1, 2
End Sub

Public Sub HideDataRows(WrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Pwd As String = "", Optional LastRowCol As Long = 3, Optional CheckColumn As Long = 2)

    With WrkSht
        If Pwd <> "" Then
            .Unprotect Pwd
        End If
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Range is one row above the data you want to filter.
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CheckColumn), .Cells(LastRow, CheckColumn))
    
        DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Hide", VisibleDropDown:=False
        
        If Pwd <> "" Then
            .Protect Pwd
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub
```

[With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)